# How to convert object datetime.time.now() to object datetime.timedelta()?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm using the `datetime.time.now()` for the current time, i.e. I want to perform an operation that counts in the totals of the hours (e.g. `1h:45min - 0h:50min`). I cannot convert the current time to the `datetime.timedelta` object.

Comment: A time is not a timedelta.  A timedelta is the difference between two times.  If the current time is 13:45:56, what timedelta do you want?

Comment: You can convert `now()` to a `timedelta` by subtracting some start time from it, like midnight. `timedelta`s are all relative.

Comment: I want to compare the actual time with a time I choose myself, like time_1 = datetime.now() time_2 = sunrise[int(11):int(13)] - 30 minutes but the two are different objects

Answer (score 0):

There is no `datetime.time.now()` — you must mean `datetime.now()` which returns a `datetime` instance which has a year, month, and day as well as the time of day. If you want a different time on the same day you can use its attributes to construct one.

If you subtract two `datetime`s the result is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).
You can also subtract an arbitrary `timedelta` from a `datetime` (resulting in another `datetime`).

Note that `timedelta` instances only have the attributes `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds`, so if you want to know how long they are in hours and minutes, you have to manually calculate them.

Here's an example of doing all of these things.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()  # Current time.
# Construct a time on the same day.
sunrise = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=6, minute=58)

if sunrise > now:  # Future
    delta = sunrise - now
    when = 'will be in'
    ago = ''
else:  # Past
    delta = now - sunrise
    when = 'happened'
    ago = 'ago'

days = delta.days
seconds = delta.seconds
hours = delta.seconds//3600
minutes = (delta.seconds//60) % 60
print(f'sunrise {when} {hours} hours {minutes} minutes {ago}')
print(f'30 minutes before sunrise today is {sunrise - timedelta(minutes=30)}')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me on this path :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it; I wanted to compare the current time with the sunrise and sunset that Python itself retrieved.
I've done it this way now (so the next one can do it too)

```
import datetime as dt   
DTN = dt.datetime.now() 

H = int(DTN .strftime("%H")) 
M = int(DTN .strftime("%M"))
S = int(DTN .strftime("%S")) 

t1 = dt.timedelta(hours= H, minutes= M, seconds=S) 
t2 = dt.timedelta(hours= 1, minutes= 0, seconds=0) 

if t1 > t2: 
    timeCal = t1-t2 }

elif t1<t2: 
    timeCal = t2-t1 

else: 
    timeCal = t1+t2 

print(timeCal)
```

actual time = 20:00:00

```
result: 19:00:00
```

Comment: You can get the time of day components of `DTN` more easily: `H = DTN.hour`, `M = DTN.minute`, and `S = DTN.second`.